# What defines "how many Spring containers will be running in my JVM"?

Tags: java, spring

Suppose I have two configuration metadata XML files: `services.xml`, `daos.xml`.

In my code I'm doing (case 1) :

```
ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "services.xml", "daos.xml" });
```

...or (case 2):

```
ApplicationContext context1 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "services.xml" });

ApplicationContext context2 = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[] { "daos.xml" });
```

So in **case 2** will I have two IoC containers in my application?

Comment: Note that you can load multiple sources for a single container.

Answer (score 0):

In second case you are explicitly creating two separate Spring Application Contexts, so yes, you'll have two of them.